# clincialtrials.gov JSON dataframe into SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

For clinicaltrials.gov data I am trying to remove brackets, parse collaborator name (can have variable number of collaborators) and parse `Phase` to just numbers. I get this error:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import sqlite3
import ssl
import ast

conn = sqlite3.connect('ctrialsdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Setup DB
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ctdata;

CREATE TABLE ctdata (
    NCTId                 TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LeadSponsorName       TEXT,
    CollaboratorName      TEXT,
    InterventionName      TEXT,
    Phase                 TEXT,
    OverallStatus         TEXT,
    Condition             TEXT,
    LastUpdatePostDate    TEXT
)
''')

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

serviceurl ='https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?'
sponsor = input('Company name: ')
url=serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'expr' : sponsor, 'fields' :
    'NCTId, LeadSponsorName,CollaboratorName,InterventionName,Phase,OverallStatus,Condition, LastUpdatePostDate',
    'min_rnk' :'1','max_rnk':'1000','fmt' :'json'})

#print(url)

urlo=urllib.request.urlopen(url, context = ctx)
urld = urlo.read().decode()
jdata = json.loads(urld)

#print(json.dumps(jdata, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(jdata['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'])
df

for child in jdata['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields']:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ctdata
    (NCTId, LeadSponsorName, CollaboratorName, InterventionName, Phase, OverallStatus, Condition, LastUpdatePostDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
                (child['NCTId'],child['LeadSponsorName'],child['CollaboratorName'],child['InterventionName'],child['Phase'], child['OverallStatus'], child['Condition'], child['LastUpdatePostDate'], ) )
conn.commit()
```

Output:

```
    Rank    NCTId   LeadSponsorName CollaboratorName    InterventionName    Phase   OverallStatus   Condition   LastUpdatePostDate
0   1   [NCT01745367]   [AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc.]    [Astellas Pharma Inc]   [Tivozanib Hydrochloride, paclitaxel, Placebo]  [Phase 2]   [Terminated]    [Triple Negative Breast Cancer] [October 27, 2020]
1   2   [NCT01673386]   [AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc.]    [Astellas Pharma Inc]   [Tivozanib, Sunitinib]  [Phase 2]   [Terminated]    [Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma]   [October 27, 2020]
2   3   [NCT02318368]   [AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc.]    [Biodesix, Inc.]    [Ficlatuzumab, Erlotinib, placebo]  [Phase 2]   [Terminated]    [Non-small Cell Lung Cancer]    [October 22, 2020]
3   4   [NCT01369433]   [AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc.]    []  [Tivozanib + paclitaxel, Tivozanib + temsiroli...   [Not Applicable]    [Terminated]    [Solid Tumors]  [September 1, 2020]
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 72>()
     54 #dfs = (jdata['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields'])
     55 #dfs
     56 
   (...)
     69 #    Condition = child[7]
     70 #    LastUpdatePostDate = child[8]
     72 for child in jdata['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields']:
---> 73      cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ctdata
     74      (NCTId, LeadSponsorName, CollaboratorName, InterventionName, Phase, OverallStatus, Condition, LastUpdatePostDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',         (child['NCTId'],child['LeadSponsorName'],child['CollaboratorName'],child['InterventionName'],child['Phase'], child['OverallStatus'], child['Condition'], child['LastUpdatePostDate'], ) )
     75 conn.commit()

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

JSON Structure:

```
{
    "StudyFieldsResponse": {
        "APIVrs": "1.01.05",
        "DataVrs": "2022:09:26 23:26:47.947",
        "Expression": "AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc.",
        "NStudiesAvail": 428928,
        "NStudiesFound": 42,
        "MinRank": 1,
        "MaxRank": 1000,
        "NStudiesReturned": 42,
        "FieldList": [
            "NCTId",
            "LeadSponsorName",
            "CollaboratorName",
            "InterventionName",
            "Phase",
            "OverallStatus",
            "Condition",
            "LastUpdatePostDate"
        ],
        "StudyFields": [
            {
                "Rank": 1,
                "NCTId": [
                    "NCT01745367"
                ],
                "LeadSponsorName": [
                    "AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc."
                ],
                "CollaboratorName": [
                    "Astellas Pharma Inc"
                ],
                "InterventionName": [
                    "Tivozanib Hydrochloride",
                    "paclitaxel",
                    "Placebo"
                ],
                "Phase": [
                    "Phase 2"
                ],
                "OverallStatus": [
                    "Terminated"
                ],
                "Condition": [
                    "Triple Negative Breast Cancer"
                ],
                "LastUpdatePostDate": [
                    "October 27, 2020"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Rank": 2,
                "NCTId": [
                    "NCT01673386"
                ],
                "LeadSponsorName": [
                    "AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc."
                ],
                "CollaboratorName": [
                    "Astellas Pharma Inc"
                ],
                "InterventionName": [
                    "Tivozanib",
                    "Sunitinib"
                ],
                "Phase": [
                    "Phase 2"
                ],
                "OverallStatus": [
                    "Terminated"
                ],
                "Condition": [
                    "Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma"
                ],
                "LastUpdatePostDate": [
                    "October 27, 2020"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Rank": 3,
                "NCTId": [
                    "NCT02318368"
                ],
                "LeadSponsorName": [
                    "AVEO Pharmaceuticals, Inc."
                ],
                "CollaboratorName": [
                    "Biodesix, Inc."
                ],
                "InterventionName": [
                    "Ficlatuzumab",
                    "Erlotinib",
                    "placebo"
                ],
                "Phase": [
                    "Phase 2"
                ],
                "OverallStatus": [
                    "Terminated"
                ],
                "Condition": [
                    "Non-small Cell Lung Cancer"
                ],
                "LastUpdatePostDate": [
                    "October 22, 2020"
                ]
```

Comment: What do you get for `for child in jdata['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields']: print(type(child['NCTId']))`?

Comment: Thank you, I get Class 'list' I believe all the data is type list

Comment: In addition, the jdata is class 'dict'

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this process - simple fix:

```
data = jdata['StudyFieldsResponse']['StudyFields']
#type(data)
dflat=(flatten(record, '.') for record in data)
df=pd.DataFrame(dflat)
```

Anyone else have better ideas please post, always looking to improve!
Thanks to Pchemguy - when I started looking at type (his question) I realized I needed to flatten the list. Cheers, MJRBBQ